# Django - TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to make a raw query on Django, here is what i tried:

```
Summary = myTable.objects.raw("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME (unixtime, '%Y/%m/%d') AS ndate, count(id) AS query_count FROM myTable GROUP BY ndate ORDER BY query_count DESC")
```

The problem is that i keep getting the following error: `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

What is the problem here? If i execute this query on MYSQL, it will work. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, '%Y/%m/%d' waiting until values are provided like you do in **string.format()** function. From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/):

> Note that if you want to include literal percent signs in the query,
> you have to double them in the case you are passing parameters:
>
> cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = '30%'") # error
> cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = '30%%'")

Comment: I tried to put a date instead of that, but it still doesn't work; also the same exact query works on mysql but not with django